# Is Ionic Framework based on Angular or not?

Tags: ionic-framework

I read that Ionic is based on Angular but it seems not when I inspect the source code (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework)...

So someone can tell me if Ionic is based on Angular or not ?

Read the source code
browse the website
web researches

I am expecting a simple response : yes/not with the proof

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

No.

You can integrate Ionic with Angular or not. As said in the first page of [Ionic website](https://ionicframework.com/):

> We don’t make assumptions about the JS Frameworks you prefer to build with. That’s why we engineered Ionic to integrate seamlessly with all best frontend frameworks, including Angular, React, Vue, or even no framework.